How to make a network request in an iOS Interactive Widget AppIntent that uses completion blocks
I have an interactive Widget for iOS 17+ that when a user taps in a Widget button, the AppIntent should contact the backend and perform an action, and retrieve a result, either success or failure. This response should update the widget accordingly.
The API:
The backend connection is made through an old Obj-C lib that deals with certificates, hashes, encryption, etc., and the API is using completion blocks. Migrating to async await is not an option in this case.
What have I tried:
Adapt the perform() function of the AppIntent to perform the network request, wait for the completion and return, using withCheckedThrowingContinuation to bridge between the completions and async await.
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            fetcher.trigger() { result in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    continuation.resume(returning: NetworkRequestResult.success(message: "Request successful"))
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

The NetworkRequestResult was an attempt to create a type that would comform to the IntentResult protocol, as all my attempts using .result() were failing with the compiler:
struct NetworkRequestResult: IntentResult {
    var value: Never? { nil }
    
    var description: String
    
    static func success(message: String) -> NetworkRequestResult {
        NetworkRequestResult(description: message)
    }
    
    static func failure(message: String) -> NetworkRequestResult {
        NetworkRequestResult(description: message)
    }
}

The debugger points out a crash in case of a successful response inside the completion block, "Fatal error: Unsupported IntentResult type". Any .result() attempts fail with the compiler "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'result'".
How can I handle the completions in the AppIntent perform method?

Have you tried to convert the error with enum Error: Swift.Error, CustomLocalizedStringResourceConvertible ? To know more AppIntent error handling  you can check Dive into App Intents

I have found a way around for now, which was moving the withCheckingThrowingContinuation to a separate private method, and then making the perform() method return .result(). I haven't fully understand why though
